# File read while it is written to

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to read a file, and process while it may be opened by another program.
I know I can lock the file but as the files are opened by a server, I only want to read them, check and maybe save a copy, so I prefer sharing read and write access to be able to read them.

Now, my first question is what happens when the file is changed while I am reading it? Do I get my own copy of the files, or I can read sudden changes of the file by another process?
If that's the case, how for example Windows Copy File option works? What happens when I copy a file, and while it is copying, some process changes it? Do I get a bad file? Obviously it never happened for me, but it there an official documentation or answer on that? Maybe I can use this way.
I saw similar questions, but I wanted to ask, as Windows Copy made me curious of how it works, and maybe there is a way for me.

In my tests, I am using CreateFileW with FILE_SHARE_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE and FILE_SHARE_DELETE. My tests show that I will see the changes if I edit the file with another process while I am reading it.

Comment: You can certainly open a file for read access and write sharing, and then read from the file while other apps are actively writing to it. You will see the data that has been committed to the file so far, and subsequent reads can see new data that has been written. I wrote my own real-time logger and viewer that is based on that exact premise and it has been working just fine for years.

Comment: If thats the case, should Windows copy a half old half new file? For example if I have a file with all 0, and in the middle of windows copy, I change it to all 1. Would Windows copy half 0 and half 1? That would be bad file in my eyes, and I never saw such file. I think there is a snapshot mechanism or is it understand the file change and copy again? I want to read the file, but atomically, so either old version or new.

Comment: The premise of your question depends entirely on the contents of the file. What defines a "bad file" ? If one process is reading and another process is writing, this may be perfectly fine if the process reading is expecting that situation and knows how to handle it.

Comment: Sure if you are writing a live log viewer. But I am asking as the view of Windows Copy. You certainly don't want a text file or a excel file, half old and half new while because of sudden write while you were copying. I hope I cleared my question and confusion.

Comment: If you don't want other apps writing to the file while you are reading from it, then simply don't open it with write sharing enabled to begin with. If you let them write while you are reading, then yes, you are going to end up with a mix of old and new data.

Comment: Then how Windows copy works? It can copy even locked files and I am curious.

Comment: @RemyLebeau And totally unrelated, I used your answers for years, and Indy is great. Thank you!